# Skipping pytest unless a parameter is present

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use unittest.skiptest but only skip a test if a parameter is given at command line.  This lets me do integration tests easier.  How can I do this?

Comment: The title does not fit the question: The title asks how to default skip a test, i.e. without any command line parameter present. This is what I would like to achieve. But it turns out this question is not the same as my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084190/default-skip-test-unless-command-line-parameter-present-in-py-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is filled with helpful information. You'll find what you are looking for [here](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option).

No need to use skiptest at all.

Basically, just use the `conftest.py` file to define a new command line option and then go about marking the tests with your new annotation. *Note: The annotation and parameter can be different..*

Answer (score 2):

You can use markers for that. You mark the task with a tag, and with the `-m` command line argument you can write logical expressions (de)selecting the tests for running.

```
@pytest.mark.slowtest
def test_case1():
    pass
```

To skip it, run it like this:

```
py.test -m 'not slowtest'
```

Docs: https://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html