# Default skip test unless command line parameter present in py.test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a long run test, which lasts 2 days, which I don't want to include in a usual test run. I also don't want to type command line parameters, that would deselect it and other tests at every usual test run. I would prefer to select a default-deselected test, when I actually need it. I tried renaming the test from `test_longrun` to `longrun` and use the command

```
py.test mytests.py::longrun
```

but that does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507713/skipping-pytest-unless-a-parameter-is-present turned out to be the opposite to my question.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) explains how to skip tests according to a command-line option.

Comment: See also these (as yet unmarked) duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559524/pytest-how-to-skip-tests-unless-you-declare-an-option-flag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246154/python-using-pytest-to-skip-test-unless-specified

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try to decorate your test as `@pytest.mark.longrun`

in your `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--longrun', action='store_true', dest="longrun",
                 default=False, help="enable longrundecorated tests")

def pytest_configure(config):
    if not config.option.longrun:
        setattr(config.option, 'markexpr', 'not longrun')
```

Comment: This will disable markers set with `pytest -m`. To avoid that, append `and not longrun` if `markexpr` already has a value.

Comment: Is `conftest.py` a file that `pytest` knows about?

Comment: @Everett yes it is the default pytest configuration file https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re#conftest-py-plugins

Answer (score 30):

Alternatively to the `pytest_configure` solution above I had found `pytest.mark.skipif`.

You need to put `pytest_addoption()` into `conftest.py`

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--longrun', action='store_true', dest="longrun",
                 default=False, help="enable longrundecorated tests")
```

And you use `skipif` in the test file.

```py
import pytest

longrun = pytest.mark.skipif("not config.getoption('longrun')")

def test_usual(request):
    assert False, 'usual test failed'

@longrun
def test_longrun(request):
    assert False, 'longrun failed'
```

In the command line

```
py.test
```

will not execute `test_longrun()`, but

```
py.test --longrun
```

will also execute `test_longrun()`.

Comment: This permutation of [sax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300672/sax)'s [already useful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181491/2809027) is even *more* useful. A standard `skipif`-based test decorator always beats a non-standard global `pytest_configure()` hack. For completeness, would you mind editing sax's full `pytest_addoption()` implementation into this solution?

Comment: **Also:** assuming you "borrow" sax's full `pytest_addoption()` implementation as is, there's no need to call `config.getoption()` to obtain this option's value. Since the name of a destination variable was passed via `dest`, the following attribute lookup suffices: `"not pytest.config.option.longrun,"`. Neat-o, eh?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Editing: no need to import pytest in `conftest.py`.

Comment: Any idea how to define `longrun` decorator in `conftest.py`? Also, "accessing pytest.config is discouraged" (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1688#issuecomment-229477812).

Comment: This is old, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883573/using-a-command-line-option-in-a-pytest-skip-if-condition

Comment: This doesn't work  in >=5.0 [due to config being removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62770650/913098). Got a workaround?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the text: the `skipif` string parameter is interpreted and can use `config`.

Answer (score 12):

This is a slightly different way.

Decorate your test with `@pytest.mark.longrun`:

```py
@pytest.mark.longrun
def test_something():
    ...
```

At this point you can run everything except tests marked with that using `-m 'not longrun'`

```
$ pytest -m 'not longrun'
```

or if you only want to run the `longrun` marked tests,

```
$ pytest -m 'longrun'
```

But, to make `-m 'not longrun'` **the default**, in `pytest.ini`, add it to `addopts`:

```
[pytest]
addopts =  
    -m 'not longrun'
    ...
```

If you want to run all the tests, you can do

```
$ pytest -m 'longrun or not longrun'
```